Is it possible to pass Gherkin steps at runtime to cucumber?
I am new to cucumber and Gherkin.  In my new role, we have inherited many very complicated and long running UI automation tests.  Updating these feature files is extremely time consuming because in order to test a small change late in the file, you have to wait 10-15 minutes (or longer!) for the test to reach that point.
I would like to write (or steal) a tool that allows me to launch my application under test and then paste chunks of gherkin script to the tool and run it against the already-running application.  That way, I can do all of the setup/preconditions once and then try different combinations of gherkin at the point in the application flow where I need to change the test.
So, I'm wondering if there is an API or library that allows me to pass Gherkin text to cucumber and have it run my glue code as normal.
Thanks!
I've searched online and did not find anything so far.

I don't think such a tool exists. Rather, you may want to improve the existing test setup such that eventually you can run your tests in parallel. This will require that each test is small and independent. Not very glamorous work, but it pays off in the long run.

I thought you might suggest that.  ;-)  That is definitely the correct BDD approach.
Unfortunately, my new team is dead set on saving time/money by consolidating several features/bug fixes into existing feature files.  I could tilt at that windmill but it would be a very uphill battle.  So, instead I want to build this tool to streamline the process of updating what we have today.  Do you know if there is an API or library I could use?  Thx!

I really don't think such a tool exists. But if you must play the role of Sancho Panza, you could fork Cucumber JVM and try to hack something in the execution loop in TestCase. You might spawn a JFrame with an input box and halt execution until a next step is provided.
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/589b12cb28fe796afe1ad226e559eaaf3bcac3fb/cucumber-core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/runner/TestCase.java#L83
